# Add HTML form on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an HTML form in my website/application.

The form has lots of fields of input text, select, and PHP code, as well, to fill drop down values.

Is there any way I can clone/create the same form when the user clicks on the Add button? Let's say, if the user clicks 5 times, it would have five forms on the UI.

**HTML**

```
<form id = "buyerForm" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-top:30px;">
<span class="customerno" style="font-size: 22px;">Buyer 1 (Form 2)</span>                                       

<div class="form-group">
<label>APPLICANT DETAILS</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Mr. / Mrs</label>
<select class="form-control" name="jnameTitle" id="jnameTitle">
<option>Please Select One</option>
<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
<option value="MS">MS</option>
</select>
</div>


// similar fields are omitted to reduce the complexity


<div class="form-group">
<label>Address</label>
<textarea name="jaddress" id="jaddress" class="form-control" cols="80" rows="5" ></textarea>                                            
</div>

<button type="submit" name="jointCustomers" id="jointCustomers" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-flat">Save</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Reset</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using jQuery (or dont mind using it) you could just use clone to add the form again to the parent container

```
$("#youButton").click(function(){   
    $("#buyerForm").clone().appendTo("#yourParentWrapper");  
});
```

see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/programndial/4569hbLa/1/)

Comment: I think you really got my question and answered well. fiddle seems fine. let me try. thanks

Comment: @simbada It's important to note that HTML ids ***must*** be unique. Therefore, after calling `.clone()` you should alter the form id like so: `var index = 0; $('#buyerForm').clone().attr('id', 'buyerForm' + index).appendTo('#yourParentWrapper'); index++;`...

Comment: @ War10ck, good point. small clarification please. I am actually cloning <div id= "jBuyer">(not form). Inside div i have <form id= "buyerForm">. So how i will make form Id unique in this case? is it correct " var index = 0;
 $("#testButton").click(function() {
   $("#jBuyer").clone()..attr('id', 'buyerForm' + index).appendTo("#jointBuyer");
   index++;
 });"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.
Lets say you have the main page -> `mainPage.php`, where you can have a list and the button (addForm).
Then you will have your `myform.php` page that will generate a form it self.

The process is very simple.

1. You press the btn AddForm
2. You make a request using AJAX against your function that generate the form in the `myform.php` page.
3. Inside your AJAX code, you will add your form inside the list object.

Note: This is only a basic idea. You must adapt the code to your needs.

```
//Your main page, will contain a list.mainPage.php
<ul id="myFORMS">
  <li><button id="idBtnElement" type="button">AddForm</button></li>
</ul> 



//Your php code to create the form. You can create a function if you want
    $arrToJSON = array(
    "myFormHtml"=>"You will put your HTML form code here"    
    );  
    return json_encode(array($arrToJSON));




//Your javaScript code
$(document).on("event", "#idBtnElement", function(){
    //Data you want to send to php evaluate
     var dt={ 
              ObjEvn:"btn_ADDFORM"
            };

    //Ajax      
     var request =$.ajax({//http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
                            url: "myFormGenerator.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: dt,
                            dataType: "json"
                        });

    //Ajax Done catch JSON from PHP 
        request.done(function(dataset){
            for (var index in dataset){ 
                 formStrHtml=dataset[index].myFormHtml;
             }

             //JavaScript 
             //Here you can grab formStrHtml in apped at the end of the list in your main page.
 $("#myFORMS ul").append('<li>'+formStrHtml+'</li>');


     }); 

    //Ajax Fail 
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        }); 
}
```

Comment: Why go through all this when a couple lines of jQuery does the same, if not better job.

Comment: this is only a option. he can use any of them.